# Camera stopped working after changing to getExternalFilesDir()

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I switched from `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)` to the supported `getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)` but now when an image is taken the camera app stops and the image isn't accessible. Using android 12.0 API 31.

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        //File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsoluteFile();

        File imageFile = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        System.out.print(storageDir);

        return imageFile;
    }
```

```
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode != INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE || mUploadMessage == null) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            return;
        }
        try {
            String file_path = mCameraPhotoPath.replace("file:","");
            File file = new File(file_path);
            size = file.length();
            Uri x =data.getData();

        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("Error!", "Error while opening image file" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        if (data != null || mCameraPhotoPath != null) {
            Integer count = 0;
            ClipData images = null;
            try {
                images = data.getClipData();
            }catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error!", e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }

            if (images == null && data != null && data.getDataString() != null) {
                count = data.getDataString().length();
            } else if (images != null) {
                count = images.getItemCount();
            }
            Uri[] results = new Uri[count];
            // Check that the response is a good one
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                if (size != 0) {
                    // If there is not data, then we may have taken a photo
                    if (mCameraPhotoPath != null) {
                        results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCameraPhotoPath)};
                    }
                } else if (data.getClipData() == null) {
                    results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(data.getDataString())};
                } else {

                    for (int i = 0; i < images.getItemCount(); i++) {
                        results[i] = images.getItemAt(i).getUri();
                    }
                }
            }

            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(results);
            mUploadMessage = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Starting with Android 11, you can't directly write files to the storage directory path instead you must use `MediaQuery` classes which you can learn more here, https://www.raywenderlich.com/10768834-scoped-storage-tutorial-for-android-11-deep-dive